# How to direct Gradle println() output or write string to file?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I would like to direct a Gradle task's println output to a file. Below is a non-working, *conceptual* example

```
task Prebuild {
  println ("hello Gradle" ) > c:/hello.txt
}
```

This doesn't work.
**What is the correct way of doing this? (if possible)**
I could find no example on SO, Google or Gradle docs.

**Alternatively, is there another way to write a string to a file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To write string to a file from a Gradle task:**

**First, Create a custom task class**

```
public class WriteStringClass extends DefaultTask {
    @TaskAction
    void writeString()
    {
      // place at top of module's "build.gradle"
      // writes string to "hello.txt" in project directory
      FileWriter fw;
      fw = new FileWriter( "hello.txt");        // create FileWriter
      fw.write( "Hello from writeString!" );    // write string to file
      fw.close();                               // needed to flush write
      println "file written."
    }
}
```

**Next, Invoke the Task:**

```
    //place within "android" closure
    task write (type:WriteStringClass) {}
```